# openvpn routing to client network

Tags: routing, openvpn

I have problem with routing on my openvpn network. What I have configured for now is openvpn server (with subnet topology) **10.10.10.0/24**. I have connected local network **10.106.255.0/24** to my openvpn server.
On the other site I have openvpn-client (home-wrt) with **10.10.10.42/24** address and local network **192.168.99.0/24**.
Both devices - openvpn **server** and **client** have *ip forwarding* turned **on**. Both iptables are accepting the forward traffic.

**What I want to achieve is to be able to connect 192.168.99.0/24 network - available via 10.10.10.42 openvpn client, from openvpn server or other openvpn clients.**

For now I'm unable to do that from any other openvpn client or even directly from openvpn server.

For each device I'm adding appropriate rule `ip r a 192.168.99.0/24 via 10.10.10.42 dev tun0`. This traffic seems to be processed by the openvpn server but it doesn't even appear on the tun device on the 10.10.10.42 client - checked with tcpdump.
On the other side when I'm trying to reach 10.106.255.0/24 (direcly connected to openvpn server) from any of the openvpn clients or even from 192.168.99.0/24 network, connections are successful.

I stuck with this problem, I'm not sure if it's an openvpn server problem, or miss-configuration in the openvpn service. Look's like openvpn is dropping this traffic. Maybe this kind of routing is not possible in client-server architecture. I don't know. Could someone help me?
Attaching the picture to have better look on the infra - [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8Vtm.jpg)

Comment: If you are using **tun** interfaces you also need to tell the OpenVPN server, where to find `192.168.99.0/24` via the **iroute** (per-client) directive like in [this guide](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/expanding-the-scope-of-the-vpn-to-include-additional-machines-on-either-the-client-or-server-subnet/#including-multiple-machines-on-the-client-side-when-using-a-routed-vpn-dev-tun).

Comment: That's it. I added iroute definition in the client config and it started working. You made my day! Thanks a lot. Wiszę Ci browarka :)